# Combining JMenu clipboard functions, accelerators, and actionMenu support (best practices)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jmenu

I've got a component with several JTables on it. I've installed custom TransferHandlers on the tables. Now, I want a means to invoke the cut/copy/paste commands on these tables, via:

1. The menubar, which works on the currently focused JTable
2. Popup menu on the JTables
3. Keyboard shortcut, which works on the currently focused JTable

JTable's actionMap already has entries for "cut", "copy", "paste". The actions for these keys do the correct thing, invoking the TransferHandler.

I've tried the following:

```
dataTable.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(cutMenuItem.getAccelerator(), "cut");
```

This works when I press cmd-X, but not when I select "cut" from the menu. I assume this is because the menu consumes the event, and it never gets to the JTable.

I can think of several hacky ways to implement this, but is there a clean way to go about it? How can I get my menu items to send their `actionCommand` to the currently focused component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how you are initializing the menu items. As `JTable` is *not* one of the text components, you may want to look at [*CCP in a non-Text Component*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/listpaste.html) with regard to setting up the `Edit` menu.

Comment: Not crazy about that CCP article (the listener leaks memory, for one thing, and the keyboard shortcuts aren't cross-platform), but it appears to be the best way to do what I want. Thanks!